# Decryption not working in Caesar cipher in Python

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

My encryption works fine, however when I run the decryption code, it doesn't work. When I get to that part of the code, an error comes up -

```
cipher2 += cipher[(cipher(A)-key1)%(len(cipher2))]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I would appreciate it if you took the time to help me.

```
alphabetL = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabetC = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
number = '0123456789'
space = ' '
Ll = len(alphabetL)
Lc = len(alphabetC)
Ln = len(number)
Lall = Ll + Lc + Ln
msgall = alphabetL + alphabetC + number + space
Question1 = input("Hello, please insert the message you want encrypted: ")
key1 = int(input("Please insert the key you want used [Keep between 1 and 26]: "))
cipher = ''
cipher2 = ''


for A in Question1:
    if A in alphabetL:
        cipher += alphabetL[(alphabetL.index(A)+key1)%Ll]
    elif A in alphabetC:
        cipher += alphabetC[(alphabetC.index(A)+key1)%Lc]
    elif A in number:
        cipher += number[(number.index(A)+key1)%Ln]
    elif A in space:
        cipher += space
    else:
        print ("Error, please use abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
print (cipher)

Question2 = input("Would you like to decrypt the message? [Y/N]: ")
if Question2 == "Y":
    for A in cipher:
        cipher2 += cipher[(cipher(A)-key1)%(len(cipher2))]
    print (cipher2)
```

Comment: The problem is with the `cipher(A)` part on the second to last line. the `cipher` variable is a string and can't be called like a function. Are you trying to call the `.index()` method instead?

Comment: I'm not sure. What would you change it to?

Comment: You might want to consider using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of calling the [`.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method on the string itself.

Comment: That didn't work sorry

Comment: What's the purpose of the `cipher(A)` call on the second to last line?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just trying to make it work. hahahaha

Comment: How can you not know? It is your code, correct? If I remember correctly, the Caesar cipher is decrypted using the same method, just shifting the letters in the other direction. You've done it in one direction, now just implement the other one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function for encrypting and decrypting.

```
alphabetL = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabetC = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
number = '0123456789'
space = ' '
Ll = len(alphabetL)
Lc = len(alphabetC)
Ln = len(number)
Lall = Ll + Lc + Ln
msgall = alphabetL + alphabetC + number + space
Question1 = input("Hello, please insert the message you want encrypted: ")
key1 = int(input("Please insert the key you want used [Keep between 1 and 26]: "))

cipher2 = ''

def ceaser_cipher(Question1,key1):
    cipher = ''
    for A in Question1:
        if A in alphabetL:
            cipher += alphabetL[(alphabetL.index(A)+key1)%Ll]
        elif A in alphabetC:
            cipher += alphabetC[(alphabetC.index(A)+key1)%Lc]
        elif A in number:
            cipher += number[(number.index(A)+key1)%Ln]
        elif A in space:
            cipher += space
        else:
            print ("Error, please use abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")

    return cipher


cipher=ceaser_cipher(Question1,key1)
print (cipher)
Question2 = input("Would you like to decrypt the message? [Y/N]: ")
if Question2 == "Y":
    cipher2=ceaser_cipher(cipher,-key1)
    print (cipher2)
```

Comment: When I run the code, the error message - "NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined" - appears. Can you give me any suggestion on what to do please?

Comment: @BigTommyVernon It means you are using python-3.x . I have updated the answer.